# Pact-jvm - Validate string values inside array with regex

Tags: java, pact, contract, pact-jvm

I have this array structure:

```
{
Array1 : ["A","B","C"],
Array2: ["D","E","F"] 
}
```

And I was validated it like this:

```
array("array1")
 .string("A")
 .string("B")
 .string("C")
.closeArray()
array("array2")
 .string("D")
 .string("E")
 .string("F")
.closeArray()
```

But my problem is that sometimes the elements inside array aren't returned by provider in the same order, so, **my question is**: How is the best way to validate it?
Considering that it will always return an array of 4 elements but with strings value in inconsistent order.
I also tried on this way:

```
.minArrayLike("array1", 1, PactDslJsonRootValue.stringMatcher("A|B|C", "A"))
.minArrayLike("array2", 1, PactDslJsonRootValue.stringMatcher("D|E|F", "D"))
```

But pact generate a contract like:

```
array1 : [A,A,A],
array2: [D,D,D]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
PactDslJsonArray.arrayEachLike()
    .stringType("A")
    .closeObject()
```

See https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/tree/master/pact-jvm-consumer-junit#dsl-matching-methods